# remove the input box's initial style

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have encoutnered some issues when trying to change the input text box initial style
this is the style I have at the moment:

```
.myInput {
    text-align: left;
    display:inline-block;
    outline: none;
    float: left;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

And I would like to remove the borders and make the input text to appear at the begining of the input control without any padding/margins that were created by the default input text box style
(I have added an image that shows the input text location versus the label's text location)

Thanks :)

Comment: Tip: accept some of your previous questions. Otherwise people wont bothre helping you

Comment: here it is: http://i47.tinypic.com/2u9s4fl.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to alter/change the default style of the textbox(myInput)
try this one.

```
.myInput{
border:0px!important;
text-align:left!important;
padding:0px!Important;
margin:0px!important;
}
```

using `!important` will prioritize your given style
hope it would help
thanks
..

Answer (score 1):

use `border:none` to remove border and add your custom style

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ux3yb/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's ever a good idea to declare so many `!important`s in your code. You're going to wind up running into several errors, because `!important` doesn't just prioritize-- it overrides aggressively.

You're better off changing `.myInput`to an ID (`#myInput`) and targeting the ID. IDs are given higher priority.

```
#myInput {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align:left;
  border: 0px;
  ...your styles here...
}
```

If you are using this input more than once, you could try wrapping it as a class under an ID and targeting that instead (`#myInput input`) I'm also wary about targeting IDs in CSS, but if it's a choice between an ID and `!important`, I'd scurry for the ID.

The `!important` command is a lovely hack, but you'll encounter too many problems from overusing it like that. Rule of thumb (and I'm not the only CSS lover on the internet who espouses this): **don't use `!important` unless it is absolutely necessary.**